Can the "weak multiplicative persistence" of positive integers be arbitrarily large?
I recently learned about the multiplicative persistence of positive integers. You fix a base $b$, and keep multiplying the base $b$ digits of a positive integer $n$ until you get to a single digit number. The number of steps to get to a single digit is called the multiplicative persistence of $n$. I have thought of making a new definition, which I call the "weak multiplicative persistence". You fix a base $b$, and take a positive integer $n$, and you multiply the non-zero digits of $n$ until you get to a single digit. The number of steps is called the weak multiplicative persistence of $n$. Now, consider a base $b$ other than $2$. Is the weak multiplicative persistence function in base $b$ bounded? Or, can it get arbitrarily large? I am asking this because it is conjectured that in base ten at least, the multiplicative persistence function is bounded, and that in fact $11$ is the least upper bound. I would love to be given even a single base where the weak multiplicative persistence is unbounded. I conjecture that in fact it is unbounded in every base other than $2$.

@NoahSchweber Well, in multiplicative persistence, you multiply zeros if there are any. Whereas in weak multiplicative persistence, you only multiply the nonzero digits.

I believe it's still bounded. Consider a four-digit number in base $10$. the largest such number is $9999$, and the product of the digits is $6561$. Decreasing any of the original digits decreases the product by more that the decrease in the original number. (For instance, $8999$ is about $9/10$ of $9999$, but its digit product must be $8/9$ of $6561$.) The same holds true for more digits. At least in base $10$, any digit product must be smaller than the number, meaning the persistence is bounded. This is obviously not a formal proof.

Or wait, do you mean the persistence is unbounded for all of $\mathbb{N}$? That would be different from my suggestion.

@EricSnyder I mean, is it unbounded for all of $\mathbb{N}$?
